# issue in jquery radio button selection

Tags: jquery

I am not much more flexible with jquery. I have some li tags and for each li tag, I have one input tag of type radio like:

```
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' id='2'>2</li>
<li class='answered'><input type='radio' name='radiooption' value='cool1' id='3'>3</li>
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' id='4'>4</li>
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' id='5'>5</li>
```

Now by jquery how to add `checked="checked"` for radio button which is under `li` tag having `class='answered'`?

Please guide me.

Comment: Start by closing those li tags, otherwise nothing will work! And the radio buttons should have the same name if they are part of a group.

Comment: and should have different ids. why does the last one have the id 2 ?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes.I have modified those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your markup first (you're missing the closing `</li>`s). As for the jQuery, something like this should do the trick:-

```
$('li.answered').children('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.answered').find('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
```